# How to pass relationship data to listview in yii2

Tags: php, listview, yii2

im trying to print an attribite from another table in yii2 Listview but im not able to get the data i need to print into the listview

```
   $query = Producto::find()->joinWith(['mPrecios']);


    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 6,
        ],
    ]);
```

Data Provider in search model

```
    $searchModel = new ProductoSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $modelCliente=new Cliente;
        $cliente = Cliente::getClientes();
        $rows = Producto::autocomplete();//Se envia la variable que contiene los productos a la vista
            return $this->render('index', array(
                                                'rows'=>$rows,
                                                'model' => $model,
                                                'modelC'=>$modelCliente,
                                                'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                                                'clientes'=>$cliente,
                                                'listDataProvider' => $dataProvider
                                                )
                                );
```

Send DtaProvider through Controller

```
   <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id'=>'listaProductos','enablePushState' => true, 'timeout' => 8000000, 'clientOptions' => ['container' => 'pjax-container']]); ?>

            <?=

              ListView::widget([
                'options'=>[
                  'class'=>'col-lg-12  list-wrapper inline row-eq-height',
                ],

                'dataProvider' => $listDataProvider,
                'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
                    $itemContent = $this->render('_tabla_producto',['model' => $model]);
                    return $itemContent;
                },
                'itemOptions' => [
                    'tag' => false,
                ],
                'summary' => '',
                'layout' => '{items}{pager}',

                'pager' => [
                    'firstPageLabel' => 'Primera',
                    'lastPageLabel' => 'Ultima',
                    'maxButtonCount' => 5,
                    'options' => [
                        'class' => ' pagination col-xs-12'
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
          ?>
            <?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
```

ListView

```
     <?php $IdProducto = $model['Refe'];?>
     <div id="producto-<?php echo $IdProducto;?>" class="content inline producto col-lg-4 box-body" >
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-6">
               <img class='img-responsive' src="<?php echo $model['ImagenProducto']?>"/>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-6" style="height:200px;">
                 <?php
                    if($model['Fraccion'] > 1){
                      echo "<button id='fraccion-$IdProducto' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs fraccionado' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalFraccion'><b>F</b></button>";
                    }
                    else{
                      echo "<button id='fraccion-$IdProducto' class='btn btn-default btn-xs disabled'><b>NF</b></button>";
                    }
                  ?><br>
                <b>Nombre:</b><br><?= $model['DescripcionCorta'] ?><br>
                <b>Presentacion:</b><br><?= $model['PresentacionCorta'] ?><br>
                <b>Precio:</b> HERE GOES THE OTHER TABLE ATTRIBUTE
              </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-6">
               <div class="input-group">
                 <span class="input-group-btn" >
                   <button id="menos-<?php echo $IdProducto;?>" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-minuse" min='0' value="0">-</button>
                 </span>
                 <input id="input-<?php echo $IdProducto;?>"  type="text" value="0" class="form-control text-center" style="height:30px;">
                 <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button id="mas-<?php echo $IdProducto;?>" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-pluss" min='0' value="0">+</button>
                 </span>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-6 pull-left">
               <button id="anadir-<?php echo $IdProducto;?>"  type="button" class="text-center center-block btn btn-sm btn-default btn-add">Añadir</button>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you have your relation set up correctly in your model, getMPrecios().

If this is a hasOne() you can access the relational data with `$model->mPrecios->attributeName` and if its a hasMany() you'll have to do a

```
foreach($model->mPrecios as $mprecios)
{
    echo $mprecios->attributeName;
}
```

This relational values should be accessible regardless of whether you eagerly load them (like you do with a joinWith()) or lazy load them.

Comment: Now it doesn't throw me any errors and relation was a hasMany() but it doesnt print any data

Comment: And you're sure it has related data stored?

Comment: Relation goes like this public function getMPrecios()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Precio::className(), ['Refe' => 'Refe']);
    } and in controller i create dataprovider like this $query = Producto::find()->with('mPrecios')->joinWith(['mPrecios']);
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,
                'pagination' => [
                    'pageSize' => 3,
                ],
            ]);

Comment: My question is: you're sure there are data stored in Precio with the Producto id in the foreign key column?

Comment: Yes it is, each table has 19867 rows properly related by the product Reference and if i perform this query it throws me the data requested SELECT mp.Refe, mp.DescripcionCorta,mp.PresentacionCorta, mpe.Precio_Unid,
        mp.ImagenProducto, mp.Fraccion
        FROM m_producto AS mp
        JOIN m_precios AS mpe
        ON mp.Refe = mpe.Refe

Comment: Could you do a var_dump() on $model->mPrecios and see what it returns?

Comment: I just double checked the shown products in start page these does not had the related price so that was the problem, thank you very much :D